# split configurations in spring - is it possible?

Tags: spring, configuration

I would like to use different controllers in spring with different application configurations.
For example lets say I have one configuration using jsf/primefaces and another one using thymeleaf (for no special reason). Is it possible to map these configurations independently to different controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but may be You can do it in two ways buy either returning view in your controller method as

```
@RequestMapping("/view1")
public String thymleaf(){
    return "thymleaf.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/view2")
public String jspView(){
    return "jspView.html";
}
```

or by configuring it in xml

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
     <property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*" />
     <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     <property name="viewNames" value="jsp/*" />
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. I thought it work but noticed just later that it did not.